# [wpa_supplicant.conf ]Stop RPi from automatically setting disable=1 to wifi networks

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

My raspberry pi automatically sets disable=1 to all the wifi networks that are not currently connected.
So when I take the Pi to other places, it won't connect it to the network automatically even though I have put the SSID and PASS to the conf file in the past.

**How can I stop my Pi from disabling the wifi networks in the wpa_supplicant.conf file?**

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the stupid GUI tool (or disable the update-config option).

---

Every time the GUI changes WiFi networks it disables all others (you would have to ask Raspberry Pi Ltd. WHY).

If disabled it does not. I don't actually use the GUI as I manually enter networks into wpasupplicant and only disable those I don't use e.g. my son's US network.

You can leave enabled if you manually edit your wpasupplicant.

`wpa_cli list_networks` will show status of devices in wpasupplicant.

---

NOTE I haven't looked for years (this Q & A is years old and I use Network Manager).

Comment: Sorry, this has been bugging me for a long time. Like, Why does this issue pop up suddenly on a pi that's been working perfectly for a long time.

Comment: Does "disable the update-config option" change other things? Could it cause other problems? Why does it work? Or do I need to accept it as one of life's little mysteries?

Comment: Cheers on the update edit! Just commenting out update config in the WPA_supplicant.conf seems to work so far. I'm only using ssh so no need for GUI.